# View is not edited

Tags: drupal, view, hosting

Today, I got free hosting space from my internet service provider. So, to test my Drupal project, I installed Drupal along with all those necessary modules (views, imageattach, Private message, search). Everything seems went well, until I tried to create a view.

When I add view and fills out all necessary field and press next, it just shows a blank white page instead of the "Views UI" edit page. I checked back in the view's list page, but no view was created. I'm not sure what causes this to happen;so I much appreciate your help.

- Drupal 6.x
- View 6.x-2.11
- Private Message - 6.x-1.3

Note: It works fine in local environment.

UPDATE : As WmasterJ suggested, I checked dblog and found that my custom module is sending header inadvertently - there was gibberish(inverted question mark) just before my opening tag. I don't know how it got there. But, anyway, I removed it and the problem solves. Thanks WebmasterJ and the rest for helping me out.

Cheers

PS : WmasterJ, just want to let you know that, I tried to clicked on check mark to indicate your post is the solution, but it doesn't work at all. "Add comment" link doesn't work either. So, don't be surprise for not seeing any indication of yours being the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips from the "[white screen of death](http://drupal.org/node/158043)" page that `mattv` posted which I would try is:

**First**, try and get some error messaging out there since this will help you to pin-point the problem and solve it faster. In you index.php file write:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

// $Id: index.php ...
```

**Second**, take a look at messages in your watchdog log at: /admin/reports/dblog

After which you will have a better understanding and can go back to the white page of death help page and read more.

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole page in the Drupal handbooks dedicated to debugging the "[White Screen of Death](http://drupal.org/node/158043)". In a nutshell, enable error reporting and check the logs. Those two steps tend to pinpoint the problem, most of the time. If that doesn't point you towards a solution, continue down the handbook page, for lots more tips.

If I had to take a wild guess, I would say your case is probably an out-of-memory error.

Answer (score 0):

If it's free space from your shared ISP, chances are you're out of memory.

Create a PHP file that contains only the following:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Load it in your browser (if you called the file "info.php", go to http://www.yoursite.com/info.php) and look for the line that says memory_limit. If it's less than 32MB, that's what's causing it - it's why the site works fine locally and most pages work fine, but the View create page takes up a lot of memory.

Also try going to the Modules page, this page can also consume a lot of memory - if you get a white screen there then this backs up the out-of-memory theory.

Your ISP may let you override the memory_limit by creating a php.ini file somewhere in your account. You should set it to at least 64M, preferably 128M+ for a complex site.